# ENOENT error : spawn on packaging ElectronJS + ReactJs + Django although it works on development mode, and paths are correct

Tags: reactjs, django, electron, pyinstaller, electron-builder

I am developing a not very common type of desktop applications, it was a web app built by ReactJS and Django, and now I want to convert it into a desktop app, I used ElectronJS for wrapping this web app so it would be a desktop app.
First I integrated ElectronJS and ReactJS together, and it worked very smoothly, then on adding the backend (Django), all I wanted was to package Django (using PyInstaller), to add the Django dist to my electron app dist, and automatically launch the Django server using electron, the rest will all happen through ReactJS and Django,

Electron is only to :

1- wrap this as a desktop app.
2- automatically launch the Django server.

This worked on the development mode, the Django server was launched, and the app worked perfectly, but on the setup of the electron app exe I got this error:

[error on setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urKau.png)

Although the paths are correct, and the same exact way I handled this works on development.

**This is my electron.js :**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev'); 

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,

    },
  });

  const djangoServerPath = isDev
    ? path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'dist', 'djangoserver', 'djangoserver.exe') 
    : path.join(process.resourcesPath,'..', 'djangoserver', 'djangoserver.exe');

  // const settingsPath = path.join(process.resourcesPath,'..', 'djangoserver', '_internal', 'einvoicing','settings.py');
  console.log(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'dist', 'djangoserver', 'djangoserver.exe'))

  // console.log(settingsPath)
  
  // const djangoServerPath = 'F:/einvoicing_react/dist/djangoserver/djangoserver.exe'; 
  const djangoProcess = spawn(djangoServerPath, ['runserver', '--noreload'], {
    cwd: __dirname, 
    // DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: settingsPath, 

  });

  djangoProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Django Output: ${data}`);
  });

  djangoProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`Django Error: ${data}`);
  });
  console.log(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"))
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"));

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    djangoProcess.kill();
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

**And this is the specfile.spec I packaged my Django Code using PyInstaller upon :**

```
# specfile.spec
# Modify this file according to your project structure

import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

project_path = Path('F:/einvoicing_react/manage.py')

added_files = [
    ('F:/einvoicing_react/dist/djangoserver/djangoserver.exe', 'djangoserver'),
    ('F:/einvoicing_react/einvoicing/settings.py', 'einvoicing'),
]

a = Analysis(
    ['manage.py'],  # Entry point to my Django project
    pathex=[str(project_path)],
    binaries=[],
    datas=added_files + collect_data_files('django'),
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=None,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=None)
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='djangoserver',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='djangoserver',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
)
```

Thanks in advance :)